# React - setting state based on object values in array.map

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a page which has a list of employee images, and clicking on them opens up a modal to display their name and job title.

I'm new to React, but I thought the way to do this would be to map over an array containing the employee details, and use an onClick event to update the state with the name/job title of the employee you've clicked on, then use that in the modal.

For example, my list of employees could look something like:

```
const people = [{name: 'Paul', title: 'some title'}, {name: 'Ben', title: 'other'}];
```

And I'm mapping over it like this:

```
const peoplelist = people.map((p, index) => {
    return (
      <img key={p.name} src={`${p.name}Illustration`} className="staffPhoto" onClick={() => THIS IS WHERE I'M STUCK} />
  );
});
```

With a view to consuming that state in my model component like this:

```
<StaffBio name={this.state.name} title={this.state.title} onClick={this.hideBio}/>
```

What I'm struggling with is what the onClick should be to capture the clicked employee's name/job title and put that in the state.

As I say, I'm new to React so I could be coming at this from completely the wrong angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply pass the details you want to a `onClick` event callback. Like

```
const peoplelist = people.map((p, index) => {
    return (
      <img key={p.name} src={`${p.name}Illustration`} className="staffPhoto" onClick={() => this.setEmployeeDetails(p.name, p.title) } />
  );
});
```

and create a callback function to set state in your component. Like

```
setEmployeeDeatils(empName, jobTitle){
  this.setState({empName: empName, jobTitle: jobTitle});
}
```

Comment: As simple as that... Thank you!